# Unit test for private Func delegate method using MBUnit's Mirror

Tags: c#, .net, mbunit, gallio

I would like to test the following class Private `Func<>` delegate method using MB Units `Mirror.ForObject()`. However it is not reflecting the method. Could any please provide a way to do this?

Functionality Code class

```
public class AccountTransaction
    {
        private static readonly Func<decimal, decimal, decimal> NetAmountCalculator = (discountedValue, discountPecentage) => discountPecentage == 100 ? 0 : Math.Round(discountedValue / (1 - (discountPecentage / 100)), 2);
    }
```

Test method

```
        /// <summary>
        /// NetAmountCalculator in normal flow
        /// </summary>
        [Test]
        public void NetAmountCalculatorTest()
        {
            var cashTransaction = Mirror.ForObject(new AccountTransaction());
            decimal discountedAmount = 90;
            decimal discountPecentage = 10;
            cashTransaction["NetAmountCalculator"].Invoke(discountedAmount , discountPecentage);
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
```

I have referred [MBUint help](http://www.gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit%3amirror) as well another nice help from [google code](http://groups.google.com/group/mbunitdev/browse_thread/thread/d216930a2d9e39d3?pli=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NetAmountCalculator` is a *field* of your class. It's not a *method* or a *property*, and therefore you cannot **invoke** it (even if it's actually a delegate so it looks like a method). What you need to do is to get the **value** of the field, to cast it correctly, and only then you may evaluate the result it returns.

```
var cashTransaction = Mirror.ForObject(new AccountTransaction());
decimal discountedAmount = 90;
decimal discountPecentage = 10;
object fieldValue = cashTransaction["NetAmountCalculator"].Value;
var func = (Func<decimal, decimal, decimal)fieldValue;
decimal actualResult = func(discountedAmount , discountPecentage);
```